# Processing of awk with multiple variable from previous processing?

Tags: awk, multiprocessing

I have a Q's for awk processing, i got a file below

cat test.txt

```
/home/shhh/
abc.c
/home/shhh/2/
def.c
gthjrjrdj.c
/kernel/sssh
sarawtera.c
wrawrt.h
wearwaerw.h
```

My goal is to make a full path from splitting sentences into `/home/jhyoon/abc.c`.

This is the command I got from someone:

```
cat test.txt | awk '/^\/.*/{path=$0}/^[a-zA-Z]/{printf("%s/%s\n",path,$0);}'
```

It works, but I do not understand well about how do make interpret it step by step.

Could you teach me how do I make interpret it?

Result :

```
/home/shhh//abc.c
/home/shhh/2//def.c
/home/shhh/2//gthjrjrdj.c
/kernel/sssh/sarawtera.c
/kernel/sssh/wrawrt.h
/kernel/sssh/wearwaerw.h
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking: to describe the command, to change it and give a proper output? Please define what is your current output, what is your desired output (if it is different) and what is the question you have.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the following:

```
$ awk '/^\//{path=$0}/^[a-zA-Z]/ {printf("%s/%s\n",path,$0)}' file
/home/jhyoon//abc.c
/home/jhyoon/2//def.c
/home/jhyoon/2//gthjrjrdj.c
/kernel/sssh/sarawtera.c
/kernel/sssh/wrawrt.h
/kernel/sssh/wearwaerw.h
```

#### Explanation

- `/^\//{path=$0}` on lines starting with a `/`, store it in the `path` variable.
- `/^[a-zA-Z]/ {printf("%s/%s\n",path,$0)}` on lines starting with a letter, print the stored `path` together with the current line.

Note you can also say

```
awk '/^\//{path=$0; next} {printf("%s/%s\n",path,$0)}' file
```

#### Some comments

- `cat file | awk '...'` is better written as `awk '...' file`.
- You don't need the `;` at the end of a block `{}` if you are executing just one command. It is implicit.

Comment: Actully I am confused like two varialbes with more ...  Could you gude me Where this guide document is located at ? Most of helping Documents just say fundmental.....

Comment: What do you mean with guide? You may want to write an introduction to awk: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html.

Comment: Sorry for asking more about your guided website!!, In there I did not find anything that i must read in order to understand above sentence

Comment: @heaven4us Explain what? Did you read the full post? In the "Explanation" section I am detailing the steps of the `awk` script. Read it carefully, check in your local machine and ask specific questions about it.