# Spliting specific word out in sentence in BASH and AWK?

Tags: bash, awk, cut, out

I got a sentence like this below

```
/home/kernel/drivers/hal
/home/kernel/drivers/hal
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/systems/linux/kernel/common
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/src
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/linux/tar/soc/
src/soc/libsoc.c
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/linux/src/soc/phy/
mt/soc/phy/x1.c
mt/soc/phy/x2.c
mt/soc/phy/x3.c
mt/soc/phy/x4.c
mt/soc/phy/x5.c
mt/soc/phy/x6.c
mt/soc/phy/x7.c
```

My goal is to make like this below

```
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/src/soc/libsoc.c
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x1.c
 /home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x2.c
 /home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x3.c
 /home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x4.c
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x5.c
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x6.c
/home/kernel/drivers/sdk/build/mt/soc/phy/x7.c
```

To archive the goal.

1. I read articles on internet many including stackoverflow...but failed to get it.
2. In Bash

   I tried to use bash builtin expression

   ```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
   Remove matching suffix pattern.
   ```

   I got this result

   ```
   /home/kernel/sdk/
   ```
3. In awk

   I am not 100% sure that this code is working well for my intention

   ```
   awk -F/ '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        {
            room[i]=$i
        };
        i=1;
        while(i<=NF)
        {
            if(room[i] == "sdk") {
                j=i;
                i=1;
                while(i<=j)
                {
                    print $i
                    i++
                }
            }
            else {
                j=i;
                i=1;
                while(i<=j)
                {
                    print $i
                    i++
                }
            }
        }
        ;getline;
    }'
   ```

   Result is

   ```
   home 
   kernel 
   drivers ....
   ```

Comment: i am sorry for not understaning it clearly,but  as i see just directory name

Comment: @heaven4us explain what the pattern is, are you searching for sdk and everything before it ?

Comment: @heaven4us a single example wouldn't be enough. Provide more no of lines along with the expected output.

Comment: ok i will put sentenses.

Comment: This is quite similar to the previous question you asked and left without clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040142/processing-of-awk-with-multiple-variable-from-previous-processing

Comment: a little bit right. but this is to cut out following specific words and concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple string substitution will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/home/test/kernel/drivers/middle/sdk/build/linux/src/soc/phy/test.c

ffname="${path##*/}"               # filename component

echo "newpath: ${path//\/build*/}/${ffname}"
```

**output:**

```
newpath: /home/test/kernel/drivers/middle/sdk/test.c
```